# Placement of text: Is this doable?

Tags: positioning

One can place text anywhere on the page provided one specifies the insertion point of where the text begins.

**Is it possible to control the placement of the text such that the user specifies where the ext ends.**

For example, in the code below, is it possible to place the text such that, for the page, the text starts on the horizontal center it **ends** on the end last line of the text frame. In the sketch below the pink area represents where the text should be. It starts with the left upper corner of the pink box, and the last line of the text is the bottom of the page text frame. (So **I** do not know where the text should start vertically; the LaTeX engine, or whatever, is supposed to calculate that.)

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    showframe,%
    paperwidth=30pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=2pc,%
]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{My chapter}

\lipsum[1]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: You can use [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) which can place textboxes anywhere on the page. And of course TikZ can do the same, bt with more overhead.

Comment: @Sveinung I think I am missing something. With `textpos`, I can tell where the box should start, the width of the box,etc. In my example, I know that it should start at the center line, and I know that where it should end; but, vertically, I do not know where it should start. How do I do that?

Comment: The plain TeX macro package `insbox` defines an`\InsertBoxL` command which wraps text around the box contents.

Comment: Should there be some full width lines at the beginning, as your image  shows? Should you have this layout for several pages?

Comment: @Bernard Edited the question. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `\vfill` to push it to the bottom, `\hfill` to push it to the right, and placed it in a `minipage` with `[b]` alignment to produce the desired width.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    showframe,%
    paperwidth=30pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=2pc,%
]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{My chapter}
\vfill\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why didn't I think of this?

Comment: @blackened Hindsight is 20/20.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    showframe,%
    paperwidth=30pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=2pc,%
]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{eso-pic, hanging} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}
\hangpara{-0.52\textwidth}{6}
\lipsum[1]
 \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{\AtTextLowerLeft{\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}\parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{\color{red}\lipsum[1]}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]